# Faster way to do complex conditional drops in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am cleaning up my files and would like to identify all the folders containing 50% or more old content.  I have printed a list of the complete filepath for each file, and the date the file was last modified.  From that list, I can extract a list of folders and subfolders where 50% of the contents were last modified earlier than 2012-01-01.  I can also drop subfolders that have already been accounted for by a parent folder.  My problem is that when I apply this code to my real dataset (~50,000 rows), it was still not complete after 5 hours of running.  How do I make it run more efficiently?

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'File': ['Group\\Division\\Department\\Document1.doc','Group\\Division\\Department\\Unit2\\Spreadsheet1.doc','Group\\Division\\Department\\Unit\\Spreadsheet2.doc','Group\\Division\\Department\\Unit\\Spreadsheet3.doc'],
        'Date': ['2012-10-08','2011-03-09','2015-12-01','2013-04-12']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['File', 'Date'])

#create a list of folders
list =[]
for f in (df.iloc[: ,0]):
    path, filename = f.rsplit("\\", 1)
    list.append(path)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(set(list))

#calculate how many files in are in a folder, and how many of those files are older than 2012, then calculate the percentage of old folders

list2 =[]
for x in (df2.iloc[: ,0]):
    for f in (df.iloc[: ,0]):
        df['CountCount'] = df['File'].str.contains(str(x),regex=False)
        countcount = df['CountCount'].sum()
        df['DateDate'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) > '2012-01-01') & df['File'].str.contains(str(x),regex=False)
        datedate = df['DateDate'].sum()
        percent = round(datedate/countcount,2)
    both = x, countcount, datedate, percent
    list2.append(both)
    
#turn list into a dataframe
    
df4 = pd.DataFrame(list2).sort_values(by=[0])

print(df4)

#make a new dataframe that drops all folders where 50% of all files are old
df5 = df4[df4[3] > .50]

df5 = df5.reset_index(drop = True)

#for every folder in df5, check to see if a subfolder exists (subfolder string will contain the parent folder path), and will have a longer len than the parent folder.  If yes, drop the subfolder
for x in (df5.iloc[: ,0]):
    df5['CountCount'] = df5[0].str.contains(str(x),regex=False) & (len(x) < df5[0].str.len())
    df5 = df5[df5.CountCount == False]
    
#resulting dataframe contains a list of folders that have 50% or more old files, and excludes their subfolders
print(df5)
```

Comment: get rid of the loops. do boolean indexing.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  To be clear, are you suggesting I should do something like `df = pd.DataFrame(df, index = [boolean condition])`?

Comment: `filtered = df.loc[sequence_of_bools, :]`